# Why are my iTunes factory equalizer presets all flat?

Tags: itunes

If I try to select any iTunes equalizer preset, they're all flat. This includes the factory ones.

[image]

How do I get them back?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your iTunes audio output set to go to an AppleTV, it will display all presets as flat. Change it to another setting, and the currently-selected equalizer preset will still display as flat. Choose a new equalizer preset, and it will look fine.

Our ATV is called "Living Room". So in the example here, I would choose "Computer", then choose a new equalizer preset, and it will work fine.

[image]